# how to transfer data of a table from Html to view.py (Python)

Tags: python, html, django

I'm using Django and I want to transform some data into view.py. I would like to know if there is a guide or method to do it. Let's say I want to transform the following into view.py

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                  <thead>
                    <!-- Columnas de la tabla -->
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">Nombre huesped</th>
                      <th scope="col">Rut huesped</th>
                      <th scope="col">Telefono</th>
                      <th scope="col">N° de habitacion</th>
                      <th scope="col">Tipo de plato</th>
                      <th scope="col">borrar</th>
                      
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id="filas">
                    <!-- Fila 1 de la tabla -->
                    
                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achieved by just returning this as an HTTPResponse:

```
def index(request):
   return HttpResponse("""<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                  <thead>
                    <!-- Columnas de la tabla -->
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">Nombre huesped</th>
                      <th scope="col">Rut huesped</th>
                      <th scope="col">Telefono</th>
                      <th scope="col">N° de habitacion</th>
                      <th scope="col">Tipo de plato</th>
                      <th scope="col">borrar</th>
                      
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id="filas">
                    <!-- Fila 1 de la tabla -->
                    
                  </tbody>
                </table>""")
```